# use npm package in laravel livewire

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, laravel-livewire, livewire-3

i am using a npm package in my livewire project.
when load the page via refresh package work fine, but when redirect with livewire navigate the package does not work, this is my code:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import '@majidh1/jalalidatepicker/dist/jalalidatepicker.min.css';
import '@majidh1/jalalidatepicker/dist/jalalidatepicker.min.js';
function create_datepicker(){
    jalaliDatepicker.startWatch({
        hideAfterChange : false,
        showEmptyBtn : false,
        autoReadOnlyInput : true,
        autoHide : false,
        time : false
    });
}
document.addEventListener('livewire:navigated', () => {
    setTimeout(create_datepicker, 200);
});
document.addEventListener('hide_datepicker', () => {
    jalaliDatepicker.hide();
});
```